# What is the time complexity of multiple recursion calls?

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

can anyone explain how we can evaluate time complexity of this function?

```
int f(int n) 
{ 
    int x,y,z,t; 
    if(n ==1 || n==0) return n; 
    x=f(n/2); 
    y=f(n/3); 
    z=f(n/4); 
    t=x+y+z; 
    if(t<n) return n; 
    return t; 
}
```

Comment: Also, notice, that you can store values of `f(x)` at array, and this will  guarantee you `O(n)` solution.

Comment: @GoogleHireMe O(1) actually if a lookup table is used (unless you store it as a linked list, but that'd be dumb)

Comment: @Bregalad I mean that you should build the look-up table first, isn't it? (:

Comment: @GoogleHireMe Oh ok, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

For non-obvious algorithms like this I always like to do an actual measurement of the complexity. You can modify your code like this:

```
size_t Counter = 0;

int f(int n) 
{ 
    ++Counter;
    ...
```

and do a simple test like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
 {
     Counter = 0;
     int Result = f(i);
     printf("%d: f(%d) = %d\n", Counter, i, Result);
 }
```

Graphs are a great way to visualize the data. For your function for `n` from `0-10000` we get (blue line is loop count, red is linear fit):

[image]

which is an obviously linear relationship. A few important caveats about this method:

- Be careful when extrapolating for larger N. For complex algorithms the behaviour may change, i.e. it may look linear for small Ns but turn into a quadratic for larger Ns (or vice-versa). If you need it for all values of N the only way is really the theoretical approach given by the other answer.
- In this case I measured the number of loops but in some cases it may be better to actually measure the function call time as a function of N. In this case the function call time is very small and it doesn't give results that are meaningful or easy to interpret (at least for the range 0-10000).

Answer (score 1):

For assessing the *Big-O* you can use [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

The main idea there is that you try to represent your recursive algorithm in the following generic form

```
T(n)=a*T(n/b)+f(n)
```

> where `a` - number of subproblems
>
> `n/b` - the size of the subproblem
>
> `f(n)` - the cost of the work done outside the recursive calls (cost
>   of the dividing the problem and merging the solutions, etc.)

Then, based on the values `a`,`b`,`f(n)` you calculate the asymptotic tight bound following the rules described on the wiki page.
I just don't want to duplicate the wiki page, as it describes the algorithm very well, and I believe that wiki page wouldn't disappear in the nearest future.